# Bash Use Origin File as Destination File

Tags: bash, imagemagick

I'm working with the ImageMagick bash tool, which uses commands of the form:

```
<command> <input filename> <stuff> <output filename>
```

I'm trying to do the following command:

```
<command> x.png <stuff> x.png
```

but for every file in a directory. I tried:

```
<command> *.png <stuff> *.png
```

But that didn't work. What's the correct way to perform such a command on every file in a directory?

Comment: I'm not sure if you could accomplish this without an intermediate file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many Unix command-line tools, such as `awk`, `sed`, `grep` are stream-based or line-oriented, which means they process files one line at a time. When using these, it is necessary to write output to an intermediate file and then rename that (with `mv`) back over the original input file. The reason for that is that you may be writing over the input file before you have read it all, so you will clobber your inputs. In that case, @sjsam's answer is absolutely correct - especially since he is careful to use the `&&` in between so that the `mv` is not done if the command is not successful.

In the specific case of ImageMagick however, and its `convert`, `compare`, `compose` commands, this is **NOT** the case. These programs are **file-oriented**, not line-oriented, so they read the **entire input file** into memory before writing any outputs. The reason is that they often need to know if there are any transparent pixels in an image before they can start processing, or how many colours there are in an image and they cannot know this till they have read the entire file. As such, it is perfectly safe, and in fact *idiomatic* to use the same input filename as output filename, like this:

```
convert image.jpg ... -crop 100x100 -colors 16 ... image.jpg
```

In answer to your question, when you have multiple files to process, the preferred method is to use the `mogrify` tool (also part of the ImageMagick suite) which is specifically intended for processing multiple files. So, you would do this:

```
mogrify -crop 100x100 -colors 16 *.jpg
```

which would overwrite your input files with the results - which is what you asked for. If you did not want it to overwrite your input files, you would add a `-path` telling ImageMagick the path to an output directory like this:

```
mogrify -path /path/to/thumbnails -thumbnail -colors 16 *.jpg
```

If you had too many files for the Windows COMMAND.EXE/CMD.EXE to expand and pass to `mogrify`, you would let ImageMagick expand the glob (the asterisk) internally like this and be able to deal with unlimited numbers of files:

```
mogrify -crop 100x100 '*.jpg'
```

The point is that not only is the `mogrify` syntax concise, and portable across Windows/OSX/Linux, it also means you only need to create **a single process** to do all your images, rather than having to write a `FOR` loop and create and execute a `convert` process and a `mv` process for each and every one of potentially thousands of files - so it is much more efficient and less error-prone.

Answer (score 1):

For a single file do like this :

```
<command> x.png <stuff> temp.png && mv temp.png x.png
```

For a set of files do like this :

```
#!/bin/bash
find `pwd` -name \*.png | while read line
do
<command> "$line" <stuff> temp.png && mv temp.png "$line"
done
```

Save the script in the folder containing the png files as `processpng`. Make it an executable and run it.

```
./processpng
```

A general version of the above script which takes the path to folder containing the above files as argument is below :

```
#!/bin/bash
find $1 -name \*.png | while read line
do
<command> "$line" <stuff> temp.png && mv temp.png "$line"
done
```

Save the script as `processpng` anywhere in the computer. Make it an executable and run it like :

```
./processpng /path/to/your/png/folder
```

**Edit:**

Incorporating @anishsane's solution, a compact way of achieving the same
results would be

```
#!/bin/bash
find $1 -name \*.png -exec bash -c "<command> {} <stuff> temp.png && mv temp.png {}"
```

In the context of `find .... -exec`:

> `{}` indicates (contains) the result(s) from the find expression. Note
>   that empty curly braces {} have no special meaning to shell so we can
>   get away without escaping {}

**Note:** Emphasis mine.

**Reference:** This [AskUbuntu Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/711452/empty-curly-braces-and-semicolon-in-bash).

Comment: That's good to know about the intermediate file. But how can I do this action for every .png file in the directory?

Comment: Use a loop to iterate through the files. See the edit.

Comment: Use `-print0` for `find` & `while IFS= read -r -d "" `, to take care of the filenames with special characters. But better yet, use `find`'s `-exec` option, when possible (it's possible here).

Comment: @anishsane : Thanks pal for the suggestion. I found difficult to incorporate the `-exec` feature here. If possible please feel free to edit the answer to add this.

Comment: `find $1 -name \*.png -exec bash -c "<command> {} <stuff> temp.png && mv temp.png {}"`

Comment: While your answer is good advice in general, please have a look at mine for the specific case of ImageMagick. Also, you should enclose all uses of `"$line"` in your scripts in double quotes else it will fail if the filenames contain any spaces.

Comment: Thankyou @MarkSetchell

Comment: @kmell96 : After going through Mark's solution, I feel that more suits your requirement. In fact I was unaware that such options existed.